# Is there a bug with the lightning data table?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I'm building a data table and everything is working well, but for whatever reason, the row border is skipped every few rows. Here's a snippet of the code and picture of the table. Anyone know what's going on or if it's a bug?

Note: These are out of the box contact names so no one real.

```
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.dataSource.dtColumnConfig}" var="rowHeader">
```

...

[image: Data Table]

Comment: I am using slds-table with no problems, you can try looking in a different browser - maybe this is related. also, you can see if the border actually exist with chrome dev tools - inspect the row element and see if it exist and only not shown

Comment: yeah it looks like it's a Firefox issue. I brought up the table in Chrome and the borders were fine.